# how to combine the running frames with the new masking frames in opencv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

i am trying to add a blur filter for the only specified range of hue, saturation, and value. and then combining my (frame, smoothed) together. but if i do it. i get a live feed where its only pure white and not the colors of my specified range of set values. is there anyway to make the mask not turn to pure white?

here is my code sample

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    lower_red = np.array([128,0,0])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,255])
    
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
    
    kernal = np.ones((15,15), np.float32)/225
    smoothed = cv2.filter2D(res, -1, kernal)
    
    fused_img  = cv2.add(frame, smoothed)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',fused_img)
    
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just now realized that the values multiply together! here is what needs to happen. you need to do addWeighted and change around the alpha until you are happy!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    lower_red = np.array([0,0,0])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,255])
    
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
    
    kernal = np.ones((15,15), np.float32)/225
    smoothed = cv2.filter2D(res, -1, kernal)
    
    fused_img  = cv2.addWeighted(smoothed, 0.1, frame, 1, 0)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res', fused_img)
    
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```